# Load More Posts Button - AJAX

Tags: wp-query, ajax, jquery, security

I'm trying to add Ajax to my theme so I can load my posts dynamically. The following code works but for some reason when I wrap the button that fires the loading with another div it doesn't do anything.

Full Code: https://pastebin.com/8DhmC32R

JS

```
jQuery(function($){ 
    $('.loadmore').click(function(){

        var button = $(this),
            data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': loadmore_params.posts, 
            'page' : loadmore_params.current_page
        };

        $.ajax({ 
            url : '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            data : data,
            type : 'POST',
            beforeSend : function ( xhr ) {
                button.text('Loading...'); 
                $('.loadmore').addClass('newcomment');
            },
            success : function( data ){
                if( data ) { 
                    button.text( 'More posts' ).prev().before(data); 
                    $('.loadmore').removeClass('newcomment');
                    loadmore_params.current_page++;

                    if ( loadmore_params.current_page == loadmore_params.max_page ) 
                        button.remove(); 

                } else {
                    button.remove();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The problem:

```
<div><button class="loadmore">Load More</button></div>
```

It works without the div class

Finally this is the first time I'm using admin-ajax.php in the frontend is it safe to use for my approach?

Thank you

Comment: So it works, just not when you put it in a `<div>`?  That's an odd behaviour.  When you check your dev tools is it still sending the data?

Comment: @TonyDjukic thanks for the reply, yes it works only if I have the `<button>` outside in anything not only in a `<div>`, `<button class="loadmore">Load More</button>`. It shows me the message in the console when the data POST successfully. I'm trying to figure out what's wrong hours now.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark and I can't even begin to 'guess' why it might help, but can you try adding an `id="loadmore"` to the button and then modifying your JS to match?  Maybe there's an ambiguity in the targeting if you wrap it.  I can't imagine there would be, but it's a small change.

Comment: @TonyDjukic Unfortunately it didn't work, here is what I'm trying to show. `<div class="show-more col-12"><button class="loadmore">Load More</button></div>` Thank you

Comment: It was worth a shot... ...this is mind boggling - it makes no sense that it doesn't work.  The only thing I'm wondering is if there's something in the success statement that prevents the returned items from being loaded if the button is wrapped in a div.  I don't see the instruction where you tell it to where to load the returned results.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @TonyDjukic [Full Code](https://pastebin.com/8DhmC32R) the function `loadmore_ajax_handler(){}` is responsible on what and how to return the posts after the button is clicked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107848/discussion-between-tony-djukic-and-trunks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a chat session between trunks (the OP) and I, here's what we discerned the issue was.

In `success` within the AJAX there was a chained series of instructions.  `.text().prev().before();`

Once the button was added into a div, this presented itself as a problem because the new posts were appearing before the button, but the button was changing, etc.

So instead, this is what works to address it, separating the actions taken and targeting both the parent div and the button. *(This is just the 'success' portion of the AJAX, the rest is all valid as it was.)*

```
success : function( data ){
    if( data ) {
        //this loads the new posts from the ajax callback
        $( '.show-more' ).prev().before(data);
        //this modifies the button
        button.text( 'More posts' ); 
        $('.loadmore').removeClass('newcomment');
        loadmore_params.current_page++;
        if ( loadmore_params.current_page == loadmore_params.max_page ) 
        button.remove(); 
    } else {
        button.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Happy to help.  :-)